# Distinguishing between inserting and updating with Slick's insertOrUpdate

Tags: scala, slick

Is there any way to know whether Slick added a new row to a table or updated an existing row when calling `insertOrUpdate`?

That function appears to always return 1, which makes a kind of sense, since one row is always affected, either by being created or by being updated.  But there doesn't seem to be any way to distinguish between these two cases.

Do I have any alternatives besides rolling my own multi-step upsert routine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.0/queries.html#upserting

```
val updated = users.insertOrUpdate(User(Some(1), "Admin", "Zeiger"))
// returns: number of rows updated

val updatedAdmin = (users returning users).insertOrUpdate(User(Some(1), "Slick Admin", "Zeiger"))
// returns: None if updated, Some((Int, String)) if row inserted
```